# Calculate increase/decrease between object key pair values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, math

I have an object, populated with objects like this:

```
tblValArr = {
  2015: { 
    jan: 32.75, 
    feb: 58.65, 
    mar: 13.28, 
    apr: 35.78, 
    may: 98.45, 
    jun: 45.69, 
    jul: 32.68, 
    aug: 75.45,
    sep: 39.87,
    oct: 95.48,
    nov: 26.78,
    dec: 12.17
  },
  2016: { 
    jan: 48.12, 
    feb: 13.56, 
    mar: 57.54, 
    apr: 14.01, 
    may: 45.84, 
    jun: 84.12, 
    jul: 78.68, 
    aug: 18.10
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
  },
};
```

Now i want to calculate the increase/decrease in percent between each key value pair (month) between 2016-2015.

Note: The array can have more than just 2 years. But I only want to do the calculations between the two latest years added to the array.

So, the result im looking for would be a new object that looks something like:

```
newArrOfDiffs = { 
    jan: 46.93%, 
    feb: -76.87%, 
    mar: ..., 
    apr: ..., 
    may: ..., 
    jun: ..., 
    jul: ..., 
    aug: ...,
    sep: ...,
    oct: ...,
    nov: ...,
    dec: ...
  },
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: What do you means by  `Nearest years` ? for example If data is available of years 2014,2015,2016 then what is nearest year ?

Comment: Then i only want to calculate the diffs between 2016-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the keys (the years), convert them to Number and sort it by Number descending. Then use the first two items only for calculation.

```js
var tblValArr = { 2015: { jan: 32.75, feb: 58.65, mar: 13.28, apr: 35.78, may: 98.45, jun: 45.69, jul: 32.68, aug: 75.45, sep: 39.87, oct: 95.48, nov: 26.78, dec: 12.17 }, 2016: { jan: 48.12, feb: 13.56, mar: 57.54, apr: 14.01, may: 45.84, jun: 84.12, jul: 78.68, aug: 18.10 } },
    newArrOfDiffs = {},
    keys = Object.keys(tblValArr).map(Number).sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });

Object.keys(tblValArr[keys[0]]).forEach(function (k) {
    newArrOfDiffs[k] = ((tblValArr[keys[0]][k] / tblValArr[keys[1]][k] - 1) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
});

console.log(newArrOfDiffs);
```

Comment: Thank you for a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run through your last year's object and then with the equation
`(difference % previousYear) * 100` you can get your percentage.

`toFixed` function formats your result to 2 decimal places.
This solution gives you strings containing the % character.
If you want just the number remove `+ '%'`
variable result holds your final object

```
let result = {}
let years = Object.keys(myObj);
let yearOne = years[years.length - 2]
let yearTwo = years[years.length - 1]
for(let month in myObj[yearTwo]){
  let monthOne = myObj[yearOne][month]
  let monthTwo = myObj[yearTwo][month]
  let difference = monthTwo - monthOne
  result[month] = ((difference / monthOne) * 100 ).toFixed(2) + '%'
}
```

Comment: I cannot set the variables "yearOne" and "yearTwo" to static values, because the key of the objects may vary. 

Sometimes the years is, 2015,2014,2013, and sometimes 2016-2015. etc

Comment: @AntonBollenForsberg you need just the last 2 years?

Comment: Yes but the two latest years can somtimes be: ex. 2015, 2014.

Comment: @AntonBollenForsberg updated the answer so the years chosen are the last two of the object

Comment: Tested your version as well. Worked fine, but Nina's solution suits my needs better. Thanks for your help though.